# Is there an \arrayrulecolor-like command to change the rule color of \fbox?

Tags: color, boxes, framed

*The question has been written above.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `fcolorbox` from the `xcolor` package or you can define your own command!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[kernelfbox]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\def\twocolorbox#1#2#3{\color{#1}\fbox{\color{#2}#3}}

\twocolorbox{blue}{red}{terrible}

\fcolorbox{gray}{yellow}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the order of arguments for `\fcolorbox` is?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\myfbox}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\fbox{\normalcolor#2}}}
\begin{document}
\myfbox{red}{This is a test}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\myfbox}[2]{\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\myfbox{red}{This is a test}
\end{document}
```