# Change border color of \fbox

Tags: color, boxes, framed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an \arrayrulecolor-like command to change the rule color of \fbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/is-there-an-arrayrulecolor-like-command-to-change-the-rule-color-of-fbox)

I'm using an `\fbox` to have a border around a `minipage`.

```
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
my content
\end{minipage}
}
```

Is there any way to set the border color of the `\fbox`?

Comment: You can also use the package `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Note that the line break after the first `{` will add a space there. You should add a `%` direct after it to avoid that. The same might be required after `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @lockstep: I see the connection to the linked question, but because it is not a very good phrased question with only minimalistic answers I'm against closing this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `xcolor` package provides `\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<text>}`. You can also use my `adjustbox` package with the `cfbox=<color>` and `minipage=<width>` keys:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% ...

\adjustbox{minipage=0.25\textwidth,cfbox=<color>}{<content>}

% or, if the whole thing should be 0.25\textwidth wide, including the border:

\adjustbox{minipage=0.25\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,cfbox=<color>}{<content>}
```

You can define your own command using:

```
\newcommand\myfbox{\adjustbox{<keys>}}
% usage: \myfbox{<content>}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend the `mdframed` package, which provides *many* options- you can frame your environment quite simply, or if you want complicated examples you can use `tikz`, `pstricks`.

The documentation has many examples, and you can find questions tagged with `mdframed` here

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mdframed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow]{myframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}    
\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\parbox{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]